# Extension Doesn't Update

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

This may be a pretty dumb question. I have Qliksense 2.0.1 desktop installed. I am creating an extension object. However, any updates I make in the .js file are never visible. I can make a change in the .qext file and those are visible. This stands true even after closing and opening Qliksense desktop.

How do you update the .js file in the extension?

As a side note, if I create a new extension with the same code in .js, it works. I just can't seem to update an extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to overcome this behavior is to change the extensions' code and test it in the browser:

- Open Qlik Sense Desktop
- At the same time open http://localhost:4848/hub/
- If the then open also Chrome Dev Tools caching is completely deactivated

Comment: Good answer, I've been a fan of your extension guides since the qlikview one!

Comment: BTW: I have described debugging a bit more in detail here: http://qliksite.io/tutorials/qliksense-visualization-extensions/part-01/04-Debugging-and-Web-Developer-Tools/

Comment: Clarification: I had to disable Caching for this to work via Chrome > Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+i) > Network Tab > Check "Disable Cache".

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a bug in 2.0.1. when testing from Qlik Sense desktop. To work around it you can open the app in the Qlik Sense hub from Google Chrome.